# Minimum number of groups such that every element in graph is included?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

### Problem Description

I have a graph containing *selectors* and *elements*. An element can have multiple selectors associated with it. As a graph, it looks something like this:

[image: Graph]

In the example, any node prefixed with an S is a selector and any node prefixed with an E is an element.

As you can see, elements can only connect with selectors. No elements will be connected with elements and no selectors will be connected to other selectors.

I want to **choose the minimum number of selectors such that their neighbors include every element in the graph**. In the above example, I would want my algorithm to return `S1, S3, S4`. *However, I don't need to return the groups that they represent.* This is illustrated below:

[image: Grouped Graph]

In the example, we do not need to use the `S2` selector as it is redundant. Furthermore, even though `E1` occurs in both `S4` and `S1`, we still need to include `S4` because of the `E5` and `E6` nodes. In other words, these groups do not need to be exact covers and can overlap if necessary.

### Possible Solution

Greedily, I could create an adjacency list of the selectors and the elements that are connected to them and select the selector with the largest elements. Then I could eliminate the elements from every other node's list and repeat the process until I have no elements left.

I would like to see if there is anything that is more efficient/elegant than this approach.

Comment: This sounds like a good question for the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), as StackOverflow is more of specific code questions, not theory

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll look into posting it there as well

Comment: Sounds like a variant of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set problem, which is NP-complete. So your solution is not guaranteed to be optimal, and there will be tradeoffs between optimality and speed.

Comment: Post it there *instead* of here, as its considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here :)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68012856/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141457/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Cross-posting risks duplicating effort and wasting the time of answerers, as they have no way to know that the question might have already received a good answer (as appears to have happened here).

Comment: @Samathingamajig, may I offer some feedback for the future, for your consideration?  When suggesting another site, in the future might you be willing to ask them to avoid cross-posting?  You could suggest they delete this copy before posting elsewhere.  I'm hoping this will provide a better experience for both askers and answerers.  Thank you for considering it!

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), where each set of elements adjacent to a selector is one of the sets in S. This is an NP-complete problem, meaning there is no efficient algorithm that always produces optimal answers. Your suggested solution is the suggested greedy solution to the problem, however it is not guaranteed to give an optimal answer. In general, there will be tradeoffs between optimality and speed for choosing an algorithm for this problem.